# xcode auto resizing xib not proper on iphone 6s plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using auto resizing xib in my application.
I disabled size class and auto layout.

this is how i set xib.
[image]

And this is how its looking on iphone 6s plus

[image]

How can i fit xib to all device without using auto layout and size class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually you set the layout for every label in left corner, thats the reason its showing full left.

for your First label `Size inspector is correct`, if you need the modification do like

[image]

for your second Label do like

[image]

for your third and Final label Set like

[image]

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `label` positions & width like see images:

**Label 1:**
[image]

**Label 2:**

[image]

**Label 3:**

[image]

**Note:** this will adjust the `uilabels` `width` & position according to the diff screen size not `height`.